What's the name of the movie where a man hides in the house of a man he's accidentally killed?
The movie is set, I think, in a middle eastern or possible eastern European country. It's about a man who works on a construction site who takes photographs of another man's wife. They fight and the woman's husband dies accidentally. The dead man's family seeks revenge for the death and they come to get the photographer. He runs away and tries to hide from them, but by coincidence he ends up hiding in the family's house. He is discovered and the family matriarch makes it clear that he is not to be harmed while he is a guest in the house. I'm not sure how the movie ends.

Berlin in Berlin (1993)
"A young German engineer photographs a beautiful Turkish woman without her permission. Her husband finds out and starts a fight. In the midst of the argument the German engineer accidentally kills the husband. With his burdened conscience, he goes out to Berlin's Turkish district to find the woman. He is spotted by her relatives, and while escaping, by strange coincidence he ends up hiding in the man's home whom he has killed. According to Turkish customs, a guest in one's household must be treated with dignity and respect even if he is the enemy. Thus, the tension and difficulties among the Turkish family and the German engineer begin. As long as he stays he will survive, but how long can he live in the home of a man he murdered?"
